# Android: Using an object not defined in XML

Tags: android, xml

Forgive the newbie question here.  From what I understand all objects that are used in an Android view must be defined in the XML, correct?  I ask because I'm creating a Class and I'd like to return a WebView from on of my methods and place that into my View after some rendering, etc.  So I guess my question is...is this a hard stop rule that everything MUST be defined in the XML of my view, if not can someone point me to a good resource showing how to do something similar to what I'm attempting here.

Comment: No, there is no such rule. You can instantiate `View`s in Java using their constructors and add them to `ViewGroup`s using the `addView` method of the `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Thanks!  I was under the understanding that all objects must be defined in the XML.  I appreciate you all being kind to a n00b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, you can define elements in XML or Java.  So for example you can declare a WebView in Java code like this:

```
 WebView webview = new WebView(this);
 webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");
 setContentView(webview);
```

The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) goes more in depth on how to work with WebViews using java code.